# PhoneGap (Cordova) CDVCommandDelegate is Nil, How Can I Get Valid Object?

Tags: ios, cordova, swift, phonegap-plugins

We are building our app with PhoneGap (Cordova).

However I have a separate Swift project where I do all native coding in Swift and then we copy over the Swift Code into the .xcodeproj built by PhoneGap.

To make life easier, I am 'installing' Cordova into my Swift project so I can mimic calls that will occur in the app built by Cordva. Basically I want to be able to call CDVPluginResult and send that result from a CDVCommandDelegate.

I have successfully installed Cordova and I am now having a hard time getting 1 thing working: My CDVCommandDelegate is always nil.

Here is my code for attempting to send an image as a base64 string:

```
//custom CDVPlugin class that I called CDVPluginDelegate
let _singleton = CDVPluginDelegate()

//handles all CDVPlugin delegation tasks
class CDVPluginDelegate: CDVPlugin
{
    class var SINGLETON:CDVPluginDelegate
    {
        return _singleton
    }
}

//getting a picture and returning it 
 //pass image to phonegap
        var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        var base64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        var cdvResult:CDVPluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsString: base64)
        println(CDVPluginDelegate.SINGLETON.commandDelegate)//PRINTS nil
        CDVPluginDelegate.SINGLETON.commandDelegate.sendPluginResult(cdvResult, callbackId: "imageSent")//crashes because command delegate is nil
```

How do I properly create/assign this CDVPluginCommand delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but you can only get a valid command delegate when you build with Cordova. If you do a build from Cordova the command delegate is valid, otherwise (if you installed Cordova as a 'plugin' to an existing app) it will be nil.